# SQL Match dates and products

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, match

I am struggling to find a way to create a table in SQL where I can consolidate all the sales dates and the products available. I have been tasked to create a table that contains a range of dates between january 1st 2022 and december 31st 2022.

My data sample consists of where date between 01/01/2022 and 31/12/2022. The date table is a table where I generated dates for the year and I have to use it to match my products and sales.

```
CREATE TABLE Date_Table (
    DateID INT     IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_Date_Table PRIMARY KEY,
    Date   DATE    NOT NULL,
    Month  TINYINT NOT NULL,
    Year   INT     NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Sales_Table (
    SaleID       INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_Sales_Table PRIMARY KEY,
    Date_of_Sale DATE NOT NULL,
    Qty_sold     INT NOT NULL,
    Total        MONEY NOT NULL,
    ProductID    INT  NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_Product_Table REFERENCES Product_table(ProductID));
);

CREATE TABLE Product_table (
    ProductID     INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_Product_Table PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductName   NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    ProductNumber NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
);
```

I am yet to find a way to be able to create a table that looks like this:

| Date | Product | "Qty Sold" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | AB1 | 0 |
| 2022-01-01 | AB2 | 2 |
| 2022-01-01 | AB3 | 1 |
| 2022-01-01 | AB4 | 0 |
| 2022-01-01 | AB5 | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 | AB1 | 3 |
| 2022-01-02 | AB2 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | AB3 | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 | AB4 | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 | AB5 | 0 |

I thus want all the dates matched with all the products even if no sale has been made. I have been working at it for some time and I can't seem to find a solution. If anyone has a little idea that could help me start it would be extremely appreciated

So far, I have just made some joins between my tables hoping that a full join might allow me to keep all the data necessary but it does not work.

Comment: please do not post image. Post the sample data as text and also include the expected result

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? If you're using a recent version then you should use `GENERATE_SERIES()` and convert the values to dates, then `JOIN` on it.

Comment: Please include the **exact** column-types, `CONSTRAINT` and `NULL`/`NOT NULL` properties of all columns and tables. Also, your `Date_Table` is... poorly designed: the `DateID`, `Month`, and `Year` columns are all redundant and if not managed correctly (and without any `CONSTRAINT`s) will contain invalid or bogus information.

Comment: You're missing `NULL`/`NOT NULL` info for `Qty_sold`, `Total`, `ProductName`, and `ProductNumber`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick with this is to first create all your rows, then only after that do you populate with the quantity sold.

The easiest way to create all rows is to do a `CROSS JOIN` e.g.,

```
SELECT Date_Table.[Date], Product_Table.ProductID, Product_Table.ProductName
FROM   Date_Table
       CROSS JOIN Product_Table
```

The above will give you a row for every product, on every date (so if 365 days for 5 products, will be 365 x 5 = 1825 rows).

With this, you then join it to your actual sales, using a LEFT JOIN so that it keeps your initial rows even if they don't have a match in sales. And to deal with the blank rows, use ISNULL to make them 0.

```
SELECT Date_Table.[Date], Product_Table.ProductID, Product_Table.ProductName,
       ISNULL(Sales_Table.Qty_sold, 0) AS Qty_Sold
FROM   (Date_Table
       CROSS JOIN Product_Table)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales_Table ON Date_Table.[Date] = Sales_Table.[Date_of_sale]
               AND Product_Table.ProductID = Sales_Table.ProductID
```

Edit:
Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NbPju7vX) with the data and SQL for you to review

Two notes about data structure setup

- Your PKs - I would usually try to make the PK meaningful (e.g., in a date table, use the date as the PK) - though it's not necessary. However, I would then suggest at least putting a nonclustered index on them so that you can look up the date (or product, etc) directly.
- I would also avoid using column names that are SQL keywords like date, month, year - and I would also consider naming columns with more meaning e.g., instead of 'Total', call it 'Total_Revenue' or 'Total_Cost'. Most of your fields follow this rule but ... just letting you know.

Comment: This is so nice of you! Thank you very much I really appreciate it.